# SOLR Query - see if multiple values are in a list of values?

Tags: java, search, solr

Basically I'm storing a permission IDs in a multi-valued field for SOLR documents.  A logged-in user must have access to ALL these IDs in order for a document to show up in their search.

For example, document "A" has permissions "1" and "5".  User "X" has access to permissions "1", "2", and "5". The user's permissions are stored externally from SOLR.

How do I write a query basically stating "field.permissions IN (1,2,5)" for solr that would return documents that have any combination of permissions "1", "2", and "5" but absolutely no other permissions?

Comment: Have you looked at Apache ManifoldCF?

Answer (score 0):

I am also storing permission in a multivalued field , and i just use OR query to match multiple emails in Solr query. Also, you can try something like this, suppose you have a field in solr as email ,so you can filter on email as email:("abc@gmail.com",def@hotmal.com") . Not too sure what this will return in this case, but it work like a contains query .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, at the moment, there is no support in solr for what you're asking. 
I can propose an alternative solution.
Instead of using a multi valued field, you can store all your permissions in a single field, for instance:

access_control: [permission1 permission2 permission3]

And use a phrase query with slop high enough to consider all the possible permutations, for instance:

a) if you're using the standard query parser: access_control: "permission1 permission2 permission3"~6
b) if you're using edismax then  qp=title~6 and q=access_control:permission1 permission2 permission3

This solution should give you only the results that you're looking for.